# Bluemix quickstart disconnects at publish with Paho MQTT client

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, paho

I used Paho MQTT client in Android to connect to IBM Bluemix quickstart IoT service. The connection part works well, but when I publish, the cloud application displays that I'm disconnected, but in the client I don't get exceptions.

I use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Connect:

```
String broker       = "tcp://quickstart.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883";
String clientId     = "d:quickstart:iotqs-sensor:myDeviceID";

try {
    client = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, null);
    MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
    client.connect(connOpts);
} catch(MqttException me) {
```

Publish:

```
String topic        = "iot-2/evt/iotsensor/fmt/jon";
String content      = "{ \"d\" : { \"data\" : 5 } }";

try {
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
    message.setQos(0);
    client.publish(topic, message);
} catch(MqttException me) {
```

The strange thing is: this code worked yesterday.
What could be the problem?
The next step will be to connect and publish to my own Bluemix IoT service, but if I can't send messages to the demo, I can't hope for more.

UPDATE:
If I connect, and publish, the quickstart app shows that I'm disconnected, but the client still lets me publish for about 3 secs, after that I get an exception: 32104 (the client is not connected).

Comment: Did you register your device as iotqs-sensor?  If so, please let me know your org.

Comment: No, I just tried to mock the bluemix web simulator, I saw it uses iotqs-sensor. But I registred a device as: type=myDevice, id=myDeviceID, org=ijlqtn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Device must be registered before it can connect.  Refer to quickstart documentation at https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/messaging/devices.html#/           I don't see any devices registered under your org.  Also, under the org it shows your email/ID as "expired".   Please sign in at https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/#/ and add yourself as a permanent user under the access tab.

Comment: I found this Playground, where I can register devices:
https://play.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/dashboard/#/devices/browse

type id= myDeviceType

device id= myDeviceID

organization= play

clientId= d:play:myDeviceType:myDeviceID

https://quickstart.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/#/device/myDeviceID/sensor/

But this way, I can't connect, not like in the previous version.

Comment: I don't see any device type iotqs-sensor registered to the play organization.

Comment: Yes, because I changed it to myDeviceType. Thank you for your help, now it's working. Now I try to connect to my own bluemix application. Is the quickstart application source available somewhere?

Comment: Are you looking for source for a client to connect via quickstart?  You can use the code here for android starter https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-starter-for-android

Comment: No (but, thank you for the link), I'm looking for the cloud visualisation part (the graph that show the data from the client). So I can deploy it with my own account and modify/play with it.

Comment: I am not sure the actual quickstart visualization code is available, but there is an iot-visualization sample available on GitHub here:  https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-visualization